# linux FIFO blocking pipe

Tags: linux, bash, fifo

If I do the following:

```
mkfifo fifo
some_command < fifo
```

"some_command" doesn't get spawned before there is data fed through "fifo".  How can resolve this without first having to send stuff down the fifo?

Comment: Using `cat` in place of `some_command` it works for me no matter which one I start first: `cat < fifo` in one terminal and `cat filename > fifo` in another.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
cat fifo | some_command
```